# Azure Media Service, VideoJS, Need to hide Azure endpoint url in src

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, video.js, azure-media-services

In Azure Media Service with VideoJS, We are creating Mainfest file and shows that video in UI,

I want to hide Azure URL or use different way to show video with out shows the Azure Cloud in frontend,

Below URL comes from Spring boot backend,

Need to hide Azure Port  from client or any other way to show video from springboot ressonce to Video.js,

Code:

```
const videoJsOptions = {
  techOrder: ['html', 'youtube', 'flash', 'other supported tech'],
  autoplay: true,
  controls: true,
  usingNativeControls: true,
  sources: [
    {
      src:
'https://**my-video.streaming.media.azure.net**/tes-122/manifest',
      type: 'application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml'
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Quick tip : Consider to also add the javascript tag

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question. Do you want to hide the video streaming URL 'https://**my-video.streaming.media.azure.net**/tes-122/manifest'  from the client?
Even if you hide it in JavaScript the client can do F12 and get the URL right?  Unless you want to implement a proxy where all requests from client go thorough the proxy and then the proxy connects to the actual Azure resource.
While a simple proxy server is sufficient, all the video data now has to be routed thorough the proxy so that needs to be quite scalable depending on how many videos you have and how many clients are viewing it at any given time.

Comment: Yes, Exactly. Can you please share with me any link documentation to configure in TypeScript or VueJs for proxy connection?

Comment: A proxy in this situation is a separate server that would act as a relay between the clients (all of them) and the Media Services streaming endpoint.  One other thing you could do is use a custom host name for the streaming endpoint as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-streaming-endpoint-concept#streaming-endpoint-properties.  Note that this does not hide the endpoint name, just changes it to something you want.

Comment: Using a proxy is transparent to the client. so no special code is needed on the client side (TypeScript/JavaScript).  Instead all media requests are made to a special proxy server and that server internally makes calls to Azure Media Services. Something like https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: But to be clear what exactly are you trying to protect?  Are worried about people download the content or sharing with people who should not be seeing it?  Then you can use things like AES encryption or DRM with authenticated  key requests https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-deliver-keys-and-licenses.  That way even if the Azure media services video URL is leaked it is unplayable since the content is encrypted.  Only a valid client can authenticate the user and then request the key.